# ruby upcase detects number as character

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a password validator and I have 2 requirements:

1. presence of an uppercase letter
2. presence of a special character (#, $, %, etc...)

when I check for uppercase letters I do the following:

```
if letter == letter.upcase
# 'a' == 'A' false
# 'A' == 'A' true
```

the problem is some special characters are being detected as upper case numbers, for example:

```
'#' == 3.upcase # returns true
```

so its throwing off my scoring. How can I differentiate between an actual uppercase letter, vs something like a number + shift becoming a special symbol?

Comment: I get "undefined method `upcase`" when doing `3.upcase`. What version of Ruby are you using? There should be no such thing as "upper case numbers". What shift-3 produces in a keyboard is highly variable.

Comment: I get the same as @tadman and `'#' == '3'.upcase #=> false`

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I see, you guys are right. I made a mistake with my statement. It seems to be another thing happening with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try testing if your character is a letter. You can use regular expressions for that:

```
def is_upcase?(character)
  # If it's a character from a to z
  if character =~ /[a-zA-Z]/
    character == character.upcase
  else
    # Do whatever you want with it
    false
  end
end
```

There is probably some gem or library that is messing up with your `upcase` method (or you are using an old or unkown ruby version). `'3'.upcase` should return `'3'`, not `'#'`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing that:

```
SPECIAL_CHARS = Regexp.escape "#$%"
  #=> "\\#\\$%"
```

**#1**

```
def both?(str)    
  str.index(/[A-W]/) && str.index(/[#{SPECIAL_CHARS}]/) ? true : false
end

both? "aAb$," #=> true
both? "a$bA," #=> true
both? "a$ba," #=> false
both? "abAB," #=> false
```

or

```
!!!str.index(/[A-W]/) && str.index(/[#{SPECIAL_CHARS}]/))
```

**#2**

```
def both?(str)    
  str =~ /[A-W].*[#{SPECIAL_CHARS}]|[#{SPECIAL_CHARS}].*[A-W]/ ? true : false
end

both? "aAb$," #=> true
both? "a$bA," #=> true
both? "a$ba," #=> false
both? "abAB," #=> false
```

(or `!!str =~ /.../`)